# PHP not working when accessed through a domain name, but works fine when accessed through IP

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, php

Done a basic setup of Ubuntu Server installing Apache, PHP and mysql through tasksel. When I browse to the IP address of the server it works fine and allows me to render PHP scripts fine.

I added a DNS entry for the server onto my local DNS server, calling it webdev.lazer.net

When I go to this domain name through my browser it renders HTML documents fine but if I try to view PHP scripts it doesn't render and downloads in plain text to the browser (As if the PHP parser isn't rendering .php documents).

I'm sure its some rookie mistake, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have two virtualhost blocks by any chance ?

Comment: are you sure the dns entry resolves to that ip?  try `bash$ whois YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME` to see which ip the dns entry resolves to.  also, check to see you don't have another webserver running.  i'm not sure if you have this set up via virutalhost or not, but make sure the ports are set to resolve to the appropriate webserver, in case you might have 2 running, but definitely a conf file would help

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the contents of your Apache configurations located in "sites-enabled"? It sounds as if you have different hosts set up, one responding on a NameVirtualHost base and another one serving default contents when accessed through IP. The NameVirtualHost entry will most likely miss an "ExecCGI" option so the PHP-interpreter is never executed. If you are using several site configurations, make sure you set up different access and error logs for each site, that'll make troubleshooting a bit easier.